# Open HTML page in browser

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have used this before but I cannot find the URL anymore and I was hoping someone might know.

There is a url you can input in Chrome (I have not used this on any other browsers so I don't know if it works on others) That will open a blank page and allow you to type HTML and then allow you to 'run' the code to see what it looks like.

I am aware of the chrome extensions but those are not a viable option.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so you're refering to `data:text/html, <html contenteditable>`
I found the same article on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5980134/turn-any-browser-window-into-a-quick+edit-notepad).

I don't know about running the code however.

There’s quite a few:

http://tinkerbin.com/
http://tinker.io/
http://jsfiddle.net
http://dabblet.com
http://cssdesk.com
http://jsbin.com

All of these allow for what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jsfiddle is one option:

http://www.jsfiddle.net

Hope that answers

Answer (score 0):

I went back to digging and remembered I found it on the lifehacks site. I altered my Google search and found it once more.

The command is data:text/html,

It isn't a web site just a simple html page.